# How to find records with duplicate values for some specific columns only in oracle PL/SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I work in PL/SQL Developer with Oracle.

I have this simple SQL query below:

```
  select 
          col1
          col2,
          col3,
          col4,
          col5

  from table t1
   (condition required)
  and  col1=X or col=X or...
```

and I want to select all different records having col2 and col3 with identical values. 
For example:

> **Record 1:** col2=5 col3=orange 
>  **Record 2:** col2=5 col3=orange 
>  **Record 3:**
>   col2=8 col3=apple 
>  **Record 4:** col2=8 col3=apple

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use analytic functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, count(*) over (partition by col2, col3) as cnt
      from t
     ) t
where cnt > 1
order by col2, col3;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
          t1.col1
          t1.col2,
          t1.col3,
          t1.col4,
          t1.col5
from table t1
join table t2 on t1.col2 = t2.col2 and t1.col3 = t2.col3 and t1.rowid <> t2.rowid
where ...
;
```

If you have a primary key column on the table, use that instead of `rowid`.